# iOS Select specific entries to display in table

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary, filtering

I have an array, which contains multiple dictionaries.

Formatted like this:-
Array
 - Index
   - DOW = Weekday
 - Index
   - DOW = Weekend
 - Index
   - DOW = Weekday

I want to populate a table with data from only those dictionaries containing DOW = Weekday.

What is the quickest way of enumerating this?

Note that the data will be changed via filters, and then table reloaded.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the formatting gets stripped out. But thank you for your main answer. Works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your array using `NSPredicate`, like this:

```
NSArray *data = @[
     @{@"Dow":@"Weekday", @"One":@"Two"}    // Item 0
,    @{@"Dow":@"Weekend", @"Three":@"Four"} // Item 1
,    @{@"Dow":@"Weekday", @"Five":@"Six"}   // Item 2
];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Dow=='Weekday')"];
NSArray *res = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

The code above will keep `NSArray`s items 0 and 2, and remove item 1, because it does not contain an entry where `@"Dow"` is set to `@"Weekday"`.

The `data` variable above represents the pre-filtered data in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you read Apple `UITableViewDataSource` protocol guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and perhaps [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) tutorial too.

Basically you'll want to -

1. Override `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and return the number of sections in your table (0 if it's not relevant).
2. Ovveride `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and here you can "apply" the needed filters on your dictionary and return the correct number of rows you actually want to display.

Next time you update the filters and call `reloadTable` again the above steps will filter the table correctly according to the new filters.